# Similarity search using Solr's NGramFilterFactory

Tags: solr, sunspot, similarity, n-gram, dismax

I am trying to use the NGramFilterFactory in Solr (using Sunspot in Rails) to find similar titles. I managed to add  a new field to my solr schema.xml like follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_ngrm" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="4"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

As I am using sunpsot in a rails app and therefore added the new field through a dynamic field to sunspot. This all worked and I can now search my model using the NGramFilterFactory. What I am not sure about is, how to configure solr in order to search for similar titles. Here are my concrete questions:

1. Does it make sense to use the dismax query parser when I am trying to query similar titles?
2. How can the [(Minimum 'Should' Match)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29) parameter help me to find similar titles?
3. Based on what exactly would I choose the ngram min. and max. sizes?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There's several things you could do:

1. ***dismax*** does not have fuzzy search. So if you want to return 'holmes' when the user search for 'homes' or 'halmes' it would be best if you changed to *edismax* parser.
2. ***Minimum 'Should' Match*** can help you define how flexible your search results will be depneding on the number of words that match.
   Let's suppose a user looks for *'Batman Dark Night'* and you have *'Batman Darker Night'* and 'Batman Returns' records tokenized. If mm is 2 only the *'Batman Dark Night'* will be returned because it matches the minimum number of words *'Batman' and 'Night'*. On the other hand, *'Batman Returns'* only matches one of them so it won't be returned.
3. ***NGramFilterFactory*** is good mainly for autocompleting. I think *PorterStemFilterFactory* fits better with what you are looking for. You can find some info here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Notes_about_solr.PorterStemFilterFactory